# Add class through ngClass if a disabled button is clicked

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sass

I want to be able to add a scss class ("error") to an element, if a [disabled] button is clicked. How do i achieve this?
[Angular2 disable button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535350/angular2-disable-button)
the [disabled] attribute is required, so this is not a working solution.

```
<button [disabled]="!isTermAgreed || isLoading" (click)="payForStory(paymentObject.StoryId)">
```

scss class that a span element will recieve through `[ngClass]`:

```
&.error {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a boolean property in your component, I.e. `activeClass`, listen for a click event on your button to toggle it, and then simply use `ngClass` to assign the class depending on the boolean.

`[ngClass]="'yourClass': activeClass"`

**edit**

As correctly pointed out, you can't listen to events on a disabled button. A solution to this is to wrap the element with a `div` and listen to events on that element (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294867/how-to-trigger-a-click-event-on-disabled-elements) answer for more details) or to use a class to simulate the disabled effect.

Comment: I thought of this but I was under the impression, that you couldn't listen for a click event on disabled buttons?

Comment: Thank you, that might work  - as someone here said, theres is indeed no pretty way to do this :-) Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You cannot listen for click events on a disabled button. You could add a disabled class to the button and then listen for events as normal. Please review this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ksttt

**Component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  isButtonClicked: boolean = false;

  public disableButtonClick() {
    this.isButtonClicked = true;
  }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<button [ngClass]="isButtonClicked ? 'error' : ''" (click)="disableButtonClick()" class="disabled">BUTTON</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the button is disabled, a class of button:disabled will be added by default. So you can put your styles in the class. As shown:

```
button:disabled {
 background-color: #97929248;
 cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no pretty way to do this in Angular. The way Angular is structured such that you shouldn't be manually checking the DOM except in rare circumstances. If you must do this, check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378219/angular2-template-div-on-click-check-if-element-has-class), this accepted answer has a solution that may be useful to you.

An alternative approach could be to always add the `.error` class on click, but construct your sass such that the properties of `.error` would only be activated when `.disabled` is also present.

For example:

```
<button (click)="isError = true" [ngClass]="{error: isError}">My Button</button>
```

And then in your SASS:

```
.disabled.error {
  //Your style here
}
```

Comment: How would you add the `.error` class on a click-event on a disabled button?

Comment: Added an example above. This code won't un-error the button, you'll have to add this logic yourself based on your application.

Answer (score 0):

If your button is disabled then it won't listen to the `(click)` event, In this case one thing you can do is to make it look like disabled using css and enable the disabled attribute once its clicked.

in your component:

```
clickedMe: boolean = false;
```

In your HTML:

```
<button [disabled]="(!isTermAgreed || isLoading) && clickedMe" [ngClass]="{'disableCss': (!isTermAgreed || isLoading), 'error': clickedMe && (!isTermAgreed || isLoading)}"(click)="payForStory(paymentObject.StoryId); clickedMe = true">
```

And you css will be something like:

```
.disableCss {
    background: #dddddd
}
```

Comment: This might work, thank you, i will implement and test it out.

Comment: Please see the updated answer, I had forgotten to remove the `error` class when the button will get enabled

Comment: Also, if you don't want to call the `payForStory()` when the disabled criteria is true, then you can have something like: `(click)="!(!isTermAgreed || isLoading) ? (payForStory(...)): '' ; clickedMe = true"`